# Несколько изображений и PictureCut

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Использую этот модуль. http://picturecut.tuyoshi.com.br/

Проблема в том, чтобы задать дефолтное изображение (DefaultImageButton), а именно у меня на странице несколько картинок и когда я подключаю модуль к каждому контейнеру по очереди - он берет первое значение DefaultImageButton

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#container_photo<?php echo $i; ?>").PictureCut({                
            Extensions                  : ["jpg","png","gif"],
            InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
            DefaultImageButton          : "<?php echo $option_value['option_value'];?>",
            PluginFolderOnServer        : "/assest/jquery.picture.cut/",
            FolderOnServer              : "/upload/",
            MinimumWidthToResize        : 1024,
            MinimumHeightToResize       : 630,
            EnableCrop                  : true,
            CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"                          
        });

    })
```

И соответственно для container_photo1, 2, 3 и т.д применяется DefaultImageButton      от container_photo1

Как решить.. ?=)

```
<div id="container_photo1"></div>

   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#container_photo1").PictureCut({                
                Extensions                  : ["jpg","png","gif"],
                InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
                DefaultImageButton          : "/upload/a4fed4621258.jpg",
                PluginFolderOnServer        : "/assest/jquery.picture.cut/",
                FolderOnServer              : "/upload/",
                MinimumWidthToResize        : 1024,
                MinimumHeightToResize       : 630,
                EnableCrop                  : true,
                CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"                          
            });

        })
    </script>            

    <div id="container_photo2"></div>                      

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#container_photo2").PictureCut({                
                Extensions                  : ["jpg","png","gif"],
                InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
                DefaultImageButton          : "/upload/aa6d7f8c4f4b.jpg",
                PluginFolderOnServer        : "/assest/jquery.picture.cut/",
                FolderOnServer              : "/upload/",
                MinimumWidthToResize        : 1024,
                MinimumHeightToResize       : 630,
                EnableCrop                  : true,
                CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"                          
            });

        })
    </script>            

    <div id="container_photo3"></div>                                  
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#container_photo3").PictureCut({                
                Extensions                  : ["jpg","png","gif"],
                InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
                DefaultImageButton          : "/upload/217e25f0738ae.jpg",
                PluginFolderOnServer        : "/assest/jquery.picture.cut/",
                FolderOnServer              : "/upload/",
                MinimumWidthToResize        : 1024,
                MinimumHeightToResize       : 630,
                EnableCrop                  : true,
                CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"                          
            });

        })
    </script>            
    <div id="container_photo4"></div>                                      
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#container_photo4").PictureCut({                
                Extensions                  : ["jpg","png","gif"],
                InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
                DefaultImageButton          : "/upload/cef4398d03ab.jpg",
                PluginFolderOnServer        : "/assest/jquery.picture.cut/",
                FolderOnServer              : "/upload/",
                MinimumWidthToResize        : 1024,
                MinimumHeightToResize       : 630,
                EnableCrop                  : true,
                CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"                          
            });

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: как вы задаете дефолтное значение?

Comment: DefaultImageButton          : "<?php echo $option_value['option_value'];?>",

Comment: ну так задавайте разные $option_value['option_value']

Comment: Ну так я и задаю каждый раз новые, в коде тоже везде разные стоят, а хватает всегда из самого первого.

Comment: приведите пример кода.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем придется допиливать ядро скрипта, потому что бекграунд он прилепляет посредством добавления `<style> ...background... </style>`  в `<head>` html-документа. https://github.com/tuyoshivinicius/jQuery-Picture-Cut/blob/master/src/jquery.picture.cut.js строка 273

`$('<style type="text/css" id="' + basic_dependence_css_id + '">' + ".picture-element-principal{background:url(" + Options.DefaultImageButton + ") no-repeat 50% 50%}" + ".picture-dropped{border:2px #666 dashed!important;}" + '</style>').appendTo('head')`

где `Options.DefaultImageButton` - ваша картинка, и в объекте они разные, достаточно вставить после этой строки `console.log(Options.DefaultImageButton);`.

Допилка скрипта заключается в применении бекграунда к вашим элементам при помощи, например, вставки строки `$($(this).selector).css('background', 'url(' + Options.DefaultImageButton + ') no-repeat 50% 50%');` после 273-й или даже 274-й.

Пример работающего кода: сюда не влез, запилил http://jsbin.com/vevajujugo/edit?html,output